# How to resize an image to a specific size in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-resizing

```
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("something.jpg");
IplImage* src = cvLoadImage("src.jpg");
cvSub(src, img, img);
```

But the size of the source image is different from `img`.

Is there any opencv function to resize it to the `img` size?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use [`cvResize`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?#void%20cvResize%28const%20CvArr%2a%20src,%20CvArr%2a%20dst,%20int%20interpolation%29). Or better use c++ interface (eg `cv::Mat` instead of `IplImage` and `cv::imread` instead of `cvLoadImage`) and then use `cv::resize` which handles memory allocation and deallocation itself.

Comment: Thanks. I saw cv::Mat in lots of topics which are about opencv, but I don't what it is. Where can I find some information(esp basic info) about it, and related functions like one you said?

Answer (score 36):

The two functions you need are documented here:

1. [imread](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#Mat%20imread%28const%20string&%20filename,%20int%20flags%29): read an image from disk.
2. [Image resizing](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=resize#resize): resize to just any size.

In short:

```
// Load images in the C++ format
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("something.jpg");
cv::Mat src = cv::imread("src.jpg");

// Resize src so that is has the same size as img
cv::resize(src, src, img.size());
```

And please, please, stop using the old and completely deprecated IplImage* classes

Answer (score 10):

For your information, the python equivalent is:

```
imageBuffer = cv.LoadImage( strSrc )
nW = new X size
nH = new Y size
smallerImage = cv.CreateImage( (nH, nW), imageBuffer.depth, imageBuffer.nChannels )
cv.Resize( imageBuffer, smallerImage , interpolation=cv.CV_INTER_CUBIC )
cv.SaveImage( strDst, smallerImage )
```

Answer (score 5):

Make a useful function like this:

```
IplImage* img_resize(IplImage* src_img, int new_width,int new_height)
{
    IplImage* des_img;
    des_img=cvCreateImage(cvSize(new_width,new_height),src_img->depth,src_img->nChannels);
    cvResize(src_img,des_img,CV_INTER_LINEAR);
    return des_img;
}
```

Comment: Be careful about ownership of des_img. Better use smart-pointers or the OpenCV C++ interface.

Comment: Direct answer to the question. Thank you a lot!

Comment: My pleasure. Always happy to contribute when I can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CvInvoke.Resize` for `Emgu.CV 3.0`

e.g

```
CvInvoke.Resize(inputImage, outputImage, new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100), 0, 0, Inter.Cubic);
```

Details are [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/c9c13b1e-4f15-31ea-9d40-4a76d5bee079.htm)